# How to split text column in bigrams to score against sentiment score lexicon (AFINN)?

Tags: r, nlp

I have a data frame with one column as text. I am able to split the text in to words (using unnest_tokens from tidytext), and then take the mean score for all the words. However, i also want to look at the scores for the bigrams/trigrams in my text - as AFINN lexicon also has scores for bi/tri grams, and i think that can help improve the scores to some extent.

Below is the code I am using (data is the dataset, Content is the column with text):
Step 1:

```
    review_words <- data %>%
    select(Source, Content) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, Content) %>%
    filter(!word %in% stopwords(kind="en"),
    str_detect(word, "^[a-z']+$"))
```

Step 2: (AFINN LIST only has 2 columns- word, and respective score

```
    reviews_sentiment <- review_words %>%
    inner_join(afinn_list, by = "word") %>%
    group_by(Source) %>%
    summarize(sentiment = mean(score))
```

Step 3: I join the the result back to 'data' to have an output of scores next to original text.

When i try to do the above steps with the following change in STEP 1:

```
    review_words <- data %>%
    select(Source, Content) %>%
    unnest_tokens(ngram, Content, token = "ngrams", n=2) %>%
    filter(!ngram %in% stopwords(kind="en"),
    str_detect(ngram, "^[a-z']+$"))
```

I get an empty dataframe. What am i missing here? Just need a quick fix to score bigrams just as I scored individual words.

Comment: @Jaap - thanks for the edit. But why have you taken R off? :) New in here, might have missed something.

Comment: The question is already tagged with **R**, thus no need to repeat that in the title

Comment: @Jaap - Thanks, will bear that in mind next time)

Comment: The problem was in the last str_detect statement I think - I changed it to :

    filter(!(ngram %in% stopwords("en")), !(str_detect(ngram, "[[:punct:]]")))

And it worked fine. Can someone confirm that this in fact was the issue?@Jaap